# Method that accept n Number of Parameters in C #

Tags: c#

I am Developing an windows Application, oftentimes I need to clear the Textboxes whenever the user save the Record or click on clear button.
Currently i am using this code txtboxname.text=string.empty;  for each textbox

So can it be possible to write a method that accept the n number of parameter
like reading the all the Textboxes in an array and using foreach we can clear them

the main requirement is to write a method which accept the n number of parameter
i.e The parameter size will be unknown.

If any body having idea about how to do this then please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With the [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.140).aspx) keyword.

Here is an example:

```
public void MyMethod(params int[] numbers)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
   {
       //numbers[i] is one of the parameters
   }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

> The params keyword lets you specify a
>   method parameter that takes a variable
>   number of arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), e.g. `Foo(params Bar[] bars)` will accept any number of `Bar` instances as input.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass a collection e.g. a dictionary or List to  your method as a parameter.

E.g.

```
public void DoSomething(List<myCustomObject> lst){
    ...
}
```

Comment: This would lead to an overhead, because of the cost of the list, compared to a simple array provided by the params keyword.

Comment: @SteveB but I bet you're going to turn the `[]` params into a list before you work on it anyway >:)

Comment: @mmcrae: actually, since `params` arguments are most of time a read-only array of parameter (meaning the data won't be manipulated), there's no point of converting it to a list, as array yet allows iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have an array of TextBoxes `TextBox[]` as a paremter to your method and you can then iterate over them in your method.